# Can We Change JFrame to JDialog and add APPLICATION_MODAL to it in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I mistakenly created a Swing project, using more than 10 `JFrames`, every thing is working fine. but in many cases i was feeling like creating multiple `JFrames` was not good. and i have also figured out that creating `Swing` project with multiple `JFrames` is not a good practice too.

So now it takes lot of time to rewrite the code. but my simple requirement is, i just want to convert my `JFrame` to `JDialog` and set it as  `setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);`

Comment: `i was feeling like creating multiple JFrames was not good` - that is correct. An application should have a single JFrame as the main window. Child window can then be dialogs. `i just want to convert my JFrame to JDialog` - ok, go ahead an do it.

Comment: can i simple change my [public class SalesTasks extends JFrame] to [public class SalesTasks extends JDialog] Will it Work fine?

Comment: Frame and dialog has the same API, so yes, you can do it. Simple write `externds JDialog` instead of `extends JFrame`. It could be a little bit difficult when you use UI-Designer, like NetBeans.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for; as the only answer you got basically is "yes, sure". And if that is good enough already, why the need to put up such a question?

Comment: (1-) `Will it Work fine?` - try it and then tell us what happens. You learn by trying. Then if you have a problem you post a specific question stating what you did and what the result was. The forum is not here for you do ask "what if" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this is what i have done.

My class extends JFrame

```
public class SalesTasks extends JFrame
```

i simply changed it to

```
public class SalesTasks extends JDialog
```

and in the constructor i just put

```
public class SalesTasks()
{
  setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
}
```